# Is there any code torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark/torch.cuda.synchronize() similar in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I am working on optimizing CUDA program's performance. 
I used `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark` to optimize performance and `torch.cuda.synchronize()` to synchronize CUDA applications in pytorch. 
To do the same job in tensorflow I searched a lot time whether similar code is in tensorflow, however I could'nt find anything.

I wonder is there any equivalent code to 
`torch.cuda.synchronize()` and `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark` exists in tensorflow.